# Ekadasi falling on a equinox

Tags: scripture, ekadashi

Tomorrow, Amalaki Ekadasi will be falling on the Autumnal equinox (here in South Africa). Ekadasi is based on the lunar cycle while Equinoxes are solar events. I want to find out if scriptures mention anything specific about them occuring on that same day